# Symfony 4 The file /tmp/phpFILE could not be accessed

Tags: php, symfony, docker

in my project I am using saving files, and today I have got one problem. When I want to save some files, they are saving, but I have got this error: `The file /tmp/phpFILE could not be accessed.`

https://github.com/k0v4back/shop-symfony/blob/master/src/Services/FileUploader.php 
*Error in 19 string*

It is service in that I save images.
I am using docker and nginx.

A few days ago everything worked fine

Where is my problem?

Comment: Have you updated anything maybe? Like some vendor libraries, or symfony, maybe docker itself?

Comment: I have a suggestion that everything stopped working because I cleared the cache with the command `php bin/console cache:clear`
But I'm not sure that this error was due to this

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, I edit my service.
https://github.com/k0v4back/shop-symfony/commit/9241a13fbaaa3579ba29ac4c3ce3209d368b9737